# How can you compare types using a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, types

Is it possible to say have something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd


fig_types = ['map', 'chart', 'heading']
fig_objects = [pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, str]
name_to_type = dict(zip(fig_types, fig_objects))

class my_fig_obj:
    def __init__(self, df, fig_type):
        self.df = df
        self.fig_type = fig_type

        if isinstance(df, name_to_type[fig_type]):
            print('yay')


pdf = pd.DataFrame([1,2], [3,4])

x = my_fig_obj('hello', 'heading')
y = my_fig_obj(pdf, 'map')
```

In pycharm it is stating that:

"parametrized generics cannot be used with instance and class checks"

However the code seems to run fine.

Comment: It seems to think you're trying to do something like `isinstance(lst, typing.List[int])`, which would raise an error.  Have you tried updating PyCharm?

Comment: This prints 'yay' for me.

Comment: Current situation doesn't allow me to easily update pycharm, is it safe to just ignore this error?

Comment: Linting warnings are just that, warnings. You can safely ignore them, or use a different editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this happen myself many times in PyCharm, where it will complain that my code isn't correct or that I'm doing some sort of coding no-no, even though it runs fine. I understand why some things are generally regarded as "bad" programming even though they technically work, but sometimes I wonder if PyCharm is just misinterpreting something.

I played around with your code, and when I put the dictionary construction into the Class block, PyCharm no longer reports it as an error:

```
class MyFigObj:
    fig_types = ['map', 'chart', 'heading']
    fig_objects = [pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, str]
    name_to_type = dict(zip(fig_types, fig_objects))

    def __init__(self, df, fig_type):
        self.df = df
        self.fig_type = fig_type
        if isinstance(df, name_to_type[fig_type]):
            print('yay')
        print name_to_type
```

And for whatever reason, it's OK with a dictionary of straight string values.  So this is an alternative way I got PyCharm to shut up about the error:

```
name_to_type_str = dict(zip(fig_types, [str(t) for t in fig_objects]))

class MyFigObj:

    def __init__(self, df, fig_type):
        self.df = df
        self.fig_type = fig_type
        if str(type(df)) == name_to_type_str[fig_type]:
            print('yay')
        print name_to_type
```

Comment: First one didn't work for me. The second solution did. Beware the second solution works as a hack to get around the error but causes issues for me (purely unrelated to the question) in using mock objects. I think I will just have to deal with seeing that red underline!